# AIR / ActionScript 3.0: error logging

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

in order to create a logfile if anything goes wrong during execution of my AIR app, I added a global exception handler like this:

```
        private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var error:Error = e.error;
        Logger.log("Uncaught Error:" + " - Message: " + error.message, "session");
    }
```

what this gives me in the logfile is something like this:

```
Uncaught Error - Message: Error #3003: File or directory does not exist.
```

Is there any way I can log a bit more of information? like for example what object the error has thrown?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Error.getStackTrace()`. See more details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5#getStackTrace%28%29).

Comment: To add to this, it's good to know that you're not handling an error, but having these kinds of errors means that you're not handling exceptions in your code as you should.  All these errors will come up if you're using the Flash Player debug.  When I do use the uncaught error functionality, it's normally to log to the server in the very off case that I didn't handle something properly in my code, went through all my tests and QA to go to production.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that and I usually catch exceptions. I took over a big project from another developer which almost didn't perform exception handling. I don't want to work over the whole code - but in case something goes wrong, i want to know about it. the stackTrace works only in debugging as far as i know, not in the releasebuild, right?

Comment: is it somehow possible to create the air application with debug information? for example when creating applications with c++ it's possible to include debuginformation to an app despite all the optimizations. is something like that possible with air?

Comment: I didn't heard about solutions which allow to get debug information in non-debug versions of Flash based runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

`Error.getStackTrace()` will only give at the time of debugging or when you are running your app using flash builder.

If you have made installer of `.exe` of your air app than it won't work with `Error.getStackTrace()`.